# Javascript Window Function Pass "this" as Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, window, this

I am looping thru a JSON object and I want to set clicks on fields based on a function named in the JSON Object. The function called will by window[] will be parameterised instead of hardcoded.

```
           for (var key in JSONOBJ) {

               func = window["minRule"](this);

               $('#'+ key).click(func);

           }
```

The function being called is

```
function minRule(elem){


 alert(elem.name);


}
```

and I want it applied to

```
<input type='text' name='FIELDINJSONOBJECT' id='FIELDINJSONOBJECT'/>
```

However when I refresh the page the function is being called for some reason and hasnt binded to the click. Also the alert(elem.name) is returning undefined. How do I pass this as the parameter to a function called with window[$FUNCTIONAME]

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$.each(JSONOBJ, function(key, value){
    $('#'+ key).click(function(){
        window["minRule"](value);
    });
})
```

In your case you are invoking the function `minRule` in the loop with parameter `this` where it points to the current functions scope and the value returned by it (in this case `undefined` as the `click` handler), that is the reason it is not working